# How to read a file with 3 columns without arrays or structures

Tags: c++, file, multiple-columns

What I'm trying to do is take a notepad document with 3 different lines of code and separate them because the first column is the day number (eg. 1, 2, 3, etc.) the second column is the wind speed and the third is the temperature in Celsius, there are 30 days of info in total. I need to find the average of all the wind speeds and also find the average of all the temperatures in the file. This is currently all I have at the moment because I'm not sure how to go about separating the columns, all I've been taught is about what to do with a single column of information.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num_of_lines = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int wind_speed;

    ifstream infile("weatherdata_2.txt", ios::in);

    if (!infile.is_open()) {

        cout << "Unable to read weatherdata_1.txt. File may not be present in the current directory.";
        return -1;
    }

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)

        num_of_lines++;
    }

    infile.close();

    cout << "The average of the wind speeds in the file is " << endl;
    cout << "The average of the temperatures in the file is " << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the document titled weatherdata_2:

1     14     25
2     12     31
3     5     35
4     11     33
5     8     21
6     9     35
7     12     25
8     13     34
9     8     32
10     13     28
11     6     32
12     13     29
13     6     28
14     8     35
15     5     25
16     6     28
17     8     34
18     8     21
19     3     31
20     15     22
21     5     35
22     6     33
23     12     27
24     15     27
25     12     34
26     14     23
27     14     22
28     5     21
29     7     29
30     14     22

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how many lines you have in the file you can do this:

```
// the 3 accumulators
int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 0;
int var3 = 0;

int tmp; // what we will use to store what we just read

// we will loop 30 times to get the 30 lines
for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
     // we read the first variable
     infile >> tmp;
     var1+=tmp; // add it to the accumulator
     infile >> tmp; // second variable
     var2+=tmp; // add it to the accumulator
     infile >> tmp; // third variable
     var3+=tmp; // add it to the accumulator
}
// print the averages
// divide by 30.0 in order to get the correct floating point output
std::cout << "Average var1: " << var1/30.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << "Average var2: " << var2/30.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << "Average var3: " << var3/30.0 << std::endl;
```